# Identifying a Manual Gas Shutoff Valve for Water Heater

Tags: water-heater, gas

I've been reviewing some instructions before flushing my water heater - and one of the first instructions is to shut off the gas valve to the appliance.

The trouble is, I'm just not certain enough to proceed. Is what I'm looking at is the shutoff valve mentioned in the instructions on the heater? How can I tell?

In case it isn't clear from my little collage below. The valve is located prior to the on the only pipeline leading to the "gas in" location on the honeywell thermostat whose [manual](https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/techlit/TechLitDocuments/69-0000s/69-1872EF.pdf) I've found, here.

[image: Collage and zoomed images]

Comment: I don't shut off the gas or turn down the temperature when flushing water heaters ; it has not been a problem. Another choice is to turn the water heater control to the "pilot" position , then the only flame will be the pilot and you will not need to go through the re-lite procedure or shut-off the line valve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a plug type valve. It is your gas shut off. You need wrench to turn it. You can just turn off power by unplugging electrical cord and it will be okay. Do not leave it on. If the burner lights without water in tank you can damage tank.